# Bootstrap 3.1.0 do not loading scripts?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my Wordpress template built with use of Bootstrap - scripts do not work, e.g. dropdown menu... I am sure that I'm doing everything right according to the instructions. But I do not know why my Bootstrap want to load "assets" folder though in that version (3.1.0) there is no such folder.

Location of my theme folder with Bootstrap files in it looks like that:

```
http://localhost:8888/my-site/wp-content/themes/my-theme/
```

My console says:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/jquery.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js
http://localhost:8888/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js
```

In my style.css theme file I've got only information about author of theme and this line: `@import url('css/bootstrap.min.css');`

In turn, my header.php file contains only:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you loading the scripts? You indicate how you load the stylesheets, but not the scripts themselves. Often bootstrap templates like to include those in the footer.

Comment: You're the boss :) That template had those scripts included in footer.php . But now appears the question... How to load those scripts, e.g. bootstrap-dropdown.js? Cause my dropdown nav bar still doesn't work...

Comment: I would guess you need to update the path in `footer.php`. You can always use Firebug to check whether the script are being loaded or not.

Comment: The things was to add the lastest version of jquery at the beginning and bootstrap.min.js too of course . :)